# How can I set the webcam to a mirror effect?

Tags: windows-8, video, webcam

Hello :) I just got the new Windows 8 MIU (I think that's what it's called) where the main page has all the apps and such , instead of the normal desktop. I hope you understand what I mean . But anyway , when I open the Camera , it shows up with the mirror effect already . (Where, for example, if I raise my right hand , it will show up on the right side of the screen.) But when I take a picture, it will flip the image so its opposite . Also , if I'm using the webcam for a website (such as Omegle) my video will look completely opposite . Instead of what I said before, for example if I raise my right hand, it will show up on the left side of the screen. How can I change that ? Please help me. I'm not very smart with computers so I really hope you understand what I mean . Thank you so much .

Comment: Think of the mirror - when you lift your right hand , the right side of the  reflection raised its hand, but the reflection that you see is not how you actually appear to other people, since its laterally inverted. Most apps will replicate this behavior so that you dont get confused. It appears Omegle doesn't do this for you. There is not real way to fix it. Its not a windows issue